# Python import mechanism when using a .pyd file

Tags: python, c++, import, pyd

I consume a Python package which currently uses C++ under the hood and which was only build for Python 3.8.

The package content looks like this:

```
my_package/
|
|- __init__.py
|- additional_code.py
|- my_lib.dll
|- wrapper.cp38-win_amd64.pyd
```

The `__init__.py` exposes everything from the .dll:

```
from .wrapper import *
...
```

My `main.py` consumes this as following:

```
# main.py

import my_package as pkg
pkg.my_method()
```

Currently this works only for Python 3.8 but fails for Python > 3.8.

How exactly does Python's import mechanism works here to get it also running for Python 3.9?

Is it sufficient to only add a `wrapper.cp39-win_amd64.pyd` (i.e., a wrapper build from Python 3.9) or do I need to write an own "import helper" which checks the current Python interpreter version?

I have found Python's [import documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), but I did not really find my exact use case. Maybe, someone can me point to the right direction.

Comment: "but fails for Python > 3.8." what does that mean exactly?

Comment: You left out the bits of code that actually put the `.pyd` file on `sys.path` and allow it to be imported (should be `zipextimporter`, as`zipimporter` does not support it by default) If you added that code we might be able to tell you, but it can't hurt to try it quickly.

Comment: Good catch. Sorry, I missed to mention the error message: When I run the code with Python 3.11 (3.8 works) I get the following error:     from .wrapper import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package.wrapper'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just re-compile the file using python 3.9 environment and headers, most of python's C API is pretty stable across minor versions (3.8 -> 3.9) so most code just needs to be recompiled to work for a different interpreter version.

there are two parts that contribute to a `.pyd` compiled for one version of python not working for another version until re-compiled.

1. when you use `import .wrapper`, python will look for a `.pyd` file whose name contains the version number that matches the running interpreter version, so it will be searching for `wrapper.cp39-win_amd64.pyd` then it will try to load it with [LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya), which leads to the second problem
2. when you compile a `.pyd` against python 3.8 it will link to `python38.dll`, so even if you renamed the already existing `.pyd`, it will probably fail to load. (And if it did load it will crash)

if you want your "wrapper" to work across multiple versions of python without compilation you should compile your library as a `.dll` with a C interface and load it using `ctypes`, and not depend on python C API inside your dll.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanations how the loader mechanisms in (1). Do you have  a documentation reference for this? Also thanks for the tip to make the wrapper agnostic to the Python version. I will give it a try. I will mark the answer as "accepted" if everything will work out.

Comment: @Schwefelsaeure Python documentation of [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) is good enough, but if the api is hard to use and if you can use external libraries for loading you can use [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#simple-example-abi-level-in-line) which can parse defenitions of C functions and structs.